# Register to application with Facebook or Google Plus

Tags: facebook, authorization, google-plus, telerik-appbuilder

We are a team that is developing an application in which the users must register to be part of the application, and be allowed to use it. It is a paid application. We have a standard form for normal registration, but we want to give the user a simpler choice, and simply log in with a social platform. This is done in many other applications (Spotify for example). The problem we are facing is that when a user has registered with Facebook, we get the email address and name back, and that is all we need except a password… At first, we had an idea just to set a parameter to something like “facebookVerified = true”, and then save the user like that in the database. And when the user logs in via Facebook at a later time, our database knows that it was registered as a Facebook-account, and we allow the user in without any password. 
The problem with this approach is obviously that anyone could decompile our application, edit some code so that the facebook-login is bypassed, and they would only need the mail address of the user in order to log in to our application.
Another approach would be to fetch the email and name from when the user log in, and put it in our manual register form, and force the user to choose a password. But in that case, we might as well just skip the choice to log in with Facebook, since we are forcing the user to create a “normal” account.

So, has anyone got any ideas or tips on how others solve this issue? 
Thank you! 
//Joakim

Comment: Use the access token as a password for social passwords

Comment: So the access token for a user will stay the same for ever ? I thought that the access token was only a temporary token that expires after a while.

Comment: If it expires you need to renew it.